# Replay the logs created by script?

Tags: linux, logging, scripting, audit

In our RedHat server, we ave enabled user session logging using **script** and it's logging the user sessions. But I can't find **scriptreplay** to play the logs recorded. How to read/play the logs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Red Hat removed [`scriptreplay`](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=181447) from `util-linux`. But you can download it from [here](http://www.koders.com/perl/fidABF0B418C7D5C0DE115305818FE5A6AB2C6AA73F.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To add  to what @quanta says, as you don't say which version of the OS you're using.

RHEL 6 and above has scriptreplay ( a compiled binary program) as part of the `util-linux-ng` package. If it's missing you can reinstall it with

```
yum reinstall util-linux-ng
```